# Downloading the correct file by getting the id of the clicked element

Tags: jquery

I'm adding password protection to a couple of file download links on my site. I've done this by adding an onclick event that brings up the password prompt and then on success i use a window.loaction = /path/to/file_name.zip. My code is mostly working, except that it's downloading the wrong file. If i click on the link with id="2012" it always downloads the 2011.zip.

Links code:

```
<a class="download" id="2011" href="#" onclick="promptPassword()">Download the</br> 2011 CD</a>

<a class="download" id="2011" href="#" onclick="promptPassword()">Download the</br> 2011 CD</a>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>
    $(function promptPassword(){

        var tips = $(".validateTips");



        function updateTips(t) {
            tips
                    .text(t)
                    .addClass("ui-state-highlight");
        }

        $('#password-form').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Enter": function(file_name) {
                    var file_name = $('.download').attr('id');
                    var  password = $('#password').val();

                    var data_html = "password=" + password;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'password.php',
                        data: "password=" + password,
                        success: function(password) {
                            if(password == 'true'){
                                window.location = 'downloads/' + file_name + '.zip';
                                $('#password-form').dialog( 'close' );

                            }
                            else {
                                updateTips("Incorrect Password. Please try again.")
                                $('#password').addClass("ui-state-error")
                                return false
                            }
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        });

        $( ".download")
                .click(function() {
                    $("#password-form").dialog( "open" );
        });

    });
</script>
```

My questions is:

How/Where in the promptPassword function should i get the id of the download link that activated the promptPassword event? My best guess is during the $('.download').click function, but how would i pass that to window.location = 'downloads/' + file_name + '.zip'; that's part of the $('#password-form').dialog() function.

Comment: links html are both identical with `ID=2011`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
var file_name = $('.download').attr('id');
```

When you try to get a value from a collection of elements it will only return the value of the first element in collection.

You could add an `active` class to element clicked:

```
$( ".download").click(function() {
         $("#password-form").dialog( "open" );
       $( ".download.active").removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
 });
```

The in dialog `Enter` button:

```
var file_name = $('.download.active').attr('id');
```